# Messaging app using angularjs $watch and $interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, websocket, instant-messaging, angularjs-watch

I am trying to add messaging to my angular app which has a rails backend.  To make my messaging feel 'real time' I am using the $interval directive to  make calls to my server and get the conversation between two users every 5 seconds. I am also using $watch to look at my messages and see if the object has change and if it has it will display the new conversation.

code:

```
$scope.messages = messages.messages

getNewMessage = ->
 conversation.getConverationBetweenTwoUsers($stateParams.userId).then ((messages) ->
  $scope.messages = messages.messages
  ), (error) ->
  $state.reload()


checkForNewMessages = ->
  $interval(getNewMessage, 5000)

$scope.$watch('messages.messages', checkForNewMessages, true)
```

Can someone please explain to me why I need to use websocket instead of this approach? Also, if what I am doing is a bad idea can you please explain why and what would be a better approach.

Please keep in mind that I already have users with conversations and a solution would accommodate my existing conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets allows it to truly be real time.  You don't have to fetch data from the client side.  Websockets would open a connection between the server and the client that allows the server to push any new data to the client as soon as it has been received.

You are just changing the way the data is transmitted.

With websockets, whenever a new message is generated by a client it is emitted back to the server, which listens for that new message event.  It then relays that message by emitting an event to all clients that should receive that message.

The event is what is listened for and can carry a payload (i.e., the message and user information)

Example:
Client A: emits a 'newMsg' event with a payload of '{user: user123, msg: my message, room: 512}'
Server is listening for the 'newMsg' event.
On a 'newMsg' event, the server emits that payload as an event, maybe something like:
socket.emit('512', '{user: 1234, msg: my message}')

Now, any clients connected to the server and listening for the '512' event will receive the message.  You can add whatever sort of database transactions in as well when the server is relaying messages, in order to capture the conversations.

I can't speak to rails specifically, but sockets listeners are simple to set up - 
you just create a listener function and assign a specific event to it.  When that event is triggered you run whatever logic you need to.  No fetching data and checking for changes.

Something like:

```
socket.on('myEvent', function(data) {
    //do some cool data stuff
})
```